# Usage of embed : A larger item embedded in a smaller one?

Tags: word-usage

> A lahar deposit, formed once the flow stops, consists of clasts (rocks having diameters >16 mm) **embedded** in a matrix (a mixture of particles having diameters < 8 mm). (From ACT science test passage)

Based on the Oxford dictionary definition and examples:

> ~ sth (in sth) to fix sth firmly into a substance or solid object e.g.  an operation to remove glass that was embedded in his leg

I think it should be a small thing imbedded in a larger one, but the original sentence is showing the otherwise.

Comment: I am guessing that since the matrix is a mixture pf particles, hence it is comparatively larger than a clast. Therefore, clast is embedded (or imbedded) into the matrix. Similar analogy to: _glass embedded in his feet or leg_. Smaller into a bigger one.

Comment: Imagine a rock buried in the sand on a beach.  The rock can be said to be **embedded** in the sand.  Each individual grain of sand might be smaller than the rock, but the rock is smaller than the entire expanse of the sand on the beach.  That's exactly the situation being described here.